Prisma comparing dates in raw Query
I'm using prisma node.js to compare date using raw query. However, it is returning a date that is false. Anyone also having this issue?
 const updated: any =
    await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM "public"."Test" WHERE updated_at != created_at AND updated_at > ${lastPulledAt}`;

  if (updated.length > 0) {
    console.log(
      'updated',
      lastPulledAt,
      updated[0].updated_at,
      updated[0].updated_at > lastPulledAt //returns false... which it shouldnt
    );
  }

Thisis the conosle return
updated 2024-05-10T02:51:58.794Z 2024-05-10T01:48:45.803Z false
data type seems similar. as well. any help would be appreciated
